# why is my doFilterInternal method not being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I´m trying to implement a filter that in the end will log the user navigation inside the system.

My spring context goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" /> -->
<!-- Importa configuracion de seguridad de ldap -->
<import resource="classpath:/spring/ldap-config.xml" />

<sec:http pattern="/resources" security="none" />

<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/seguridad/login.xhtml"
        access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/views/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <sec:form-login login-page="/seguridad/login.xhtml"
        authentication-failure-url="/seguridad/login.xhtml" />

    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" />

    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/seguridad/accesoDenegado.xhtml" />

    <sec:custom-filter ref="navegationFilter" after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<b:bean id="navegationFilter" class="com.praxis.desvucem.web.service.seguridad.NavegationFilter" />
```

and my filter class goes like this:

```
package com.praxis.desvucem.web.service.seguridad;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class NavegationFilter extends RequestContextFilter {

protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

@Override
// @LogMe
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.debug("Running Navegation filter");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
        logger.debug("User is trying to access site for the second time");
        logger.debug("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("Session is null");
    }

    logger.debug("Continue with remaining filters");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

So when I run it, I don´t get any kind of error and my filter is even being fired but it neve calls my doFilterInternal method.
Here is an excerpt of the log:

```
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.4.148; SessionId: 1v5ehc9tvkn7u1bft3w17n6wtv; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/seguridad/login.xhtml'; against '/seguridad/login.xhtml'
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /seguridad/login.xhtml; Attributes: [permitAll]
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.4.148; SessionId: 1v5ehc9tvkn7u1bft3w17n6wtv; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@9604a9e, returned: 1
13:33:02.889 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
13:33:02.890 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
13:33:02.890 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'NavegationFilter'
13:33:02.890 [168531621@qtp-1002845369-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /seguridad/login.xhtml reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
```

So why isn´t my doFilterInternal being called?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you extending `RequestContextFilter`?

`RequestContextFilter` is a subclass of `OncePerRequestFilter`, which contains logic that will prevent the filter class from being invoked more than once per request.

Comment: so which class should I extend if I want a generic filter?

Comment: Ok I´ve somehow managed to solve my problem by changing from RequestContextFilter to GenericFilterBean.
In the extends of my class.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestContextFilter` is a subclass of `OncePerRequestFilter`, so extend from `OncePerRequestFilter` class.

the issue that you will find after extending from `OncePerRequestFilter` class is that `FilterChain`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse` that they use the **jakarta** package while you're using **javax**.